# Keyup on selected div with .focus/.focusout (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following multiple HTML div : `<div class="draggable"></div>` (that are generated through a loop, they all share the same class).
When clicking on the div, it should add a class("verso") when pressing a keyboard key (here: right and left arrows). It does work, but how do I integrate the focus out to be able to deselect this div and select another? Something like that does not work.

```
$(".draggable")
    .draggable()
    .click(function(){
         $(this).is(":focus", function() {
            $(this).focusout();
        });
        $(this).not(":focus", function() {
            $(this).focus();
        });

        $('.draggable').on('keyup', function(e){ 
        if ((e.which == 39) || (e.which == 37)) {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('verso')) {
            $(this).addClass("verso");
            }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass("verso");
        }        
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

"that are generated through a loop, they all share the same class"

When HTML is generated, it's mostly not in the DOM when setting Click handlers.

Try using

```
$(document).on('click', '.draggable', function(){})
```

To set the click handler on the document

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code in

```
$(document).ready(() => {
   // Here goes your code
});
```

This will make sure *scripts* will be run only after DOM is ready